# Flutter create a Utility class but async function cannot be called

Tags: asynchronous, dart, flutter

My flutter app created a Utility class and would like to use the functions from utility class in different files/pages. But the the async function of Utility class cannot be called n other files. Please kindly help to solve this issue.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class Utility {

  ConnectivityResult connectivityResult;

  Future<bool> checkConnection() async{
    connectivityResult = await (new Connectivity().checkConnectivity());

    if ((connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) || (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi)){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  static void showAlert(BuildContext context, String text) {
    var alert = new AlertDialog(
      content: Container(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[Text(text)],
        ),
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        new FlatButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
            child: Text(
              "OK",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ))
      ],
    );

    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) {
          return alert;
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `static` keyword on you function

`static Future<bool> checkConnection()`

or instantiate you Utility class